# Linked list: removing first element

Tags: java, linked-list, comparative-review, memory-management

**Method 1**:

```java
public void removeFirst() {
    if (first == null) throw new NoSuchElementException();
    if (first == last) first = last = null;
    else {
        var second = first.next;
        first.next = null;
        first = second;
    }
}
```

**Method 2**:

```java
public void removeFirst() {
    if (first == null) throw new NoSuchElementException();
    if (first == last) first = last = null;
    else               first = first.next;
}
```

Which method is preferable, speed and memory-wise? Stepping through the debugger, I see no differences in `first`, `next`, and `last` objects or their `value` attributes - so 'correctness' appears the same, though I ponder about garbage collection.

---

**Base class excerpt**:

```java
public class LinkedList {
    private class Node {
        private int value;
        private Node next;

        public Node(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
    private Node first;
    private Node last;
}

public void addLast(int value){
    var new_node = new Node(value);

    if (first == null){
        first = last = new_node;
    } else {
        last.next = new_node;
        last = new_node;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't touch the code after receiving answers, it invalidates answers and tends to create a mess.

Comment: @Mast The point of my question was being missed, so I clarified it with a close equivalent. It was this or creating a "duplicate"

Comment: Yea, had we caught your edit sooner (before the answer was changed to accommodate), we'd still had to roll it back per our guidelines. If your point was being missed, that highlights why putting extra effort in the first iteration is very important on Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Mast Fair, but my original question was already clear enough, just not as explicit as the edit - but the answer, which entirely missed the point of the question (before being revised), was being upvoted, and no alternatives were being posted. Unsure what the best course of action is then, as posting a new question risked being marked as a duplicate

Answer (score 6):

Review points:

- removeFirst on an empty list should be a no-op, (or throw an exception).
- `last` was dangling.
- Setting things to null of the removed first node, is not done in OOP, is
  left to the garbage collection. This also removes the need for an extra variable. And the resulting binary code is smaller.

So:

```
public void removeFirst() {
    if (first != null) {
        if (first == last) { // Either this.
            last = null;
        }
        first = first.next;
        if (first == null) { // Or this.
            last = null;
        }
    }
}
```

One can only remove the first, when there is one.
Then the last might be the biblical first.

This is for the single linked list, where a node has just one *next* pointer.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon _setting fields/variables to null_ in order to help garbage collection faster saving memory, has almost no discernible gain (time gain in the future). As there is an extra assignment it might even be slower, **I take it that a Node is not held outside of the list.**

Comment: I like this answer, it addresses the core quesiton about having the (unnecessary) `second` variable, and it also resolves the issue with the possible dangling `last` pointer if `first == last`. It may need some better text to describe those aspects, but this is a review with good observations IMHO.

Comment: @rolfl , J. Eggen I tried keeping the question minimal, but apparently the intent wasn't too clear - see updated. The most relevant part of this answer is the third bullet point - but is that all there's to say on it? If so, that's fair, but that's the point that should be discussed/emphasized - the rest of the answer's not really relevant (also `last = null` handling is incorrect per standard implementations, as removing from an empty list should throw an exception)

Comment: My apology too. Though if the list contains one element last == first, and a removeFirst should null out `last`. The removed node, and neither its fields need not be nulled in garbage collected languages. It is bad style as it delivers noise to the code reader, and the code writer should better concentrate on functional code. For this reason I automatically just gave the most minimal code.

Comment: So can you (or anyone) confirm that _setting to null_ is **redundant**, and happens automatically by the garbage collector? This is the main idea I'm trying to understand

Comment: Yes it is redundant, the life time analysis of objects takes care of that & more efficiently. As confirmation readers may **upvote** this comment.